# Fluid layout pattern creation for webpages

Tags: web, css

I would like to have each and every page on my site to have a skeleton structure as mentioned below. Based on the template selected by the user (`saved choice/default css`) the appearance of the page changes.

I am planning to use [960.gs](http://960.gs) or blueprint CSS framework for layout handling.

I am a newbie to CSS and layouts. Best example for my requirement would be how its done on [jimdo.com](http://jimdo.com)/[weebly.com](http://weebly.com). I am looking for advice so that I can learn this fast and implement it in iterations.

Whats the best approach to solve such design problems. I am sure it needs creative bend but as of now I would like to take bookish approach so that I can use it for my own solution.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [3 column layout generator](http://www.pagecolumn.com/3_column_div_generator.htm) may help.